# Using random numbers to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{10000}e^{\frac{k}{10000}}$

Tags: probability-theory, approximation-theory

I tried using the Monte Carlo Method to approximate the sum $\sum_{1}^{10000}e^{\frac{k}{10000}}$.  First I genarating 100 random numbers in (1, 10000). Then by the strong law of large numbers:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}\frac{f(U_i)}{k} \to E[f(U)] = \theta$$

where:

$$\theta = \int_{1}^{10000}e^{\frac{x}{10000}}dx$$
The exercise says to use only 100 random numbers. So dont know if that thought is right, because this method requires k→∞

Comment: Which would be $f(U_i)$ in your example?

Comment: would be $f(x) = e^{\frac{x}{10000}}$ evaluate in points generated by the uniform (1, 10000).  $U$ is the sequence of the 100 random numbers.

Comment: This question is a little unclear: what are you (or aren't you) allowed to do as part of this problem?  What's the precise statement of the exercise?  That would go a long way towards letting us help you better.

Comment: (Otherwise I would just note that, by Euler-Maclaurin approximation, this is very close to being $10000\cdot\int_0^1 e^x dx = 10000(e-1)$ and that you can use higher-order terms in the approximation to get a very close result without doing any randomization at all.)

Comment: But we *know* the exact value of this sum, right? So, what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing a few different concepts:

- You write $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{100}f(U_i)\to\mathbb{E}[f(U)]$ when you clearly mean $\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}f(U_i)\approx\mathbb{E}[f(U)]$.
- You talk about random numbers in $\{1,\dots,10000\}$ (implying that you choose them uniformly). This is therefore a discrete random variable. To evaluate its expectation, you then integrate between 1 and 10000 as if it were continuous (and you don't even normalize the density).

Let us go back to the basics. You know that for any continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$,

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^Nf\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)\xrightarrow[N\to+\infty]{}\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

By identification, do you see what function $f$ you should choose to approximate $\sum_{k=1}^{10000}e^{k/1000}$?

Let us assume that you have found such an $f$, and $\sum_{k=1}^{10000}e^{k/1000}\approx\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. You may write

$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\mathbb{E}[f(U)],$$

where $U$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$. Then, do you see how to approximate $\mathbb{E}[f(U)]$ by using the Monte Carlo techniques you mention in your post?

Comment: The exercise asks to use 100 independent random numbers to find an approximation to the sum immediately thought the monte carlo method could help. I do not know if there's another way

Comment: If it is asked to generated some independent random variables, then Monte Carlo is the underlying technique. So this is probably the method that is expected, although it is very messy (and numerically inefficient) as other commenters have said.

Comment: That's what I thought. This method would be effective for a large k. But that's how it is in the exercise, unaware of another method

Answer (score 0):

This looks slightly messy to me, in that we are mixing to different approximations: an integral that is (numerically) approximated by a sum, and a integral (or a sum) that is (probabilistically) approximated by a Montecarlo extraction.

There is no need to convert the integral to a (approximate) sum to evaluate it via Montecarlo - and might be confusing to suggest that.

Let's say we want to evaluate

$$I=\int_0^1 e^x dx $$

On one hand, this can be approximated by a finite sum:

$$I= \frac{1}{10000}\int_0^{10000} e^{t/10000}dt\approx \frac{1}{10000} \sum_k e^{k/10000}$$

On the other (rather unrelated) hand, the integral can be evaluated via Montecarlo. Let $Y$ be a random variable uniform in $[0,1]$ Then , letting $u(y)=e^{y}$
$$E[u(Y)]=\int_{0}^1 f_Y(y)\, u(Y) dY = I$$

Then, we can evaluate the integral as an expectation, and so we can throw a large number (say $N=100$) of values of $Y$ and approximate

$$I =E(u(Y)) \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N u(Y_i) $$

Notice that this $N$ has no relation with the $10000$ above. To evaluate if this $N$ is big enough, we could try to compute the variance. Anyway, informally, if the variable is not "tricky" (if the densitiy does not varies wildly in the support), 100 (even sometimes 30) is considered a reasonable number for using the law of large numbers.